# Calling and using audio, video, and image files from database/website

Tags: android, database, resources

I am not exactly sure what the best way to do this is. To save space, I would like to have my Android app call and use audio, video, and image files from an outside source and stream it on the app. Just not sure how to do this. First off should I be putting these files I want to call on a database? Or maybe a website? Also how would I call these files from wherever it is? Any help would be appreciated. If you have any links to any tutorials pertaining to either building the database (if you recommend that) with this stuff on it and/or calling it in the app I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Oh also I am also curious about being able to upload information that can then be called by someone to be viewed. For example if you have seen those Joke apps and how you can submit a joke and seconds later it can be viewed by some other user and it automatically updates. Any info on that as well would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

audio, video and images pretty much already have repos (youtube and picasso)
its just a matter of knowing the links.  Trying to host this stuff yourself will create a lot more hassle.  if you really want to host the stuff i would recommend cloud storage.  if users have the ability to upload im sure it will fill up quickly

as for text (as well as for sharing data between users) REST services will probably be best.  you can have links to the files you want and have those links stored in your database that the REST services link up to.

best part is that REST services can also be hosted by the cloud.

Comment: I checked it out and Cloud seems like a very useful way to go. I wasn't going to let the app users upload videos, music, and images. They would have to submit them to me and only certain ones would be posted. I also wasn't going to do text I was gonna do star ratings. That was what they were going to be able to post. Still think this is the best way to go? Also do you have any idea how the rating system is stored?

Comment: well i would think u would store numbers then in your app interpret those numbers into stars.  ya for any kind of centralized storage i would recommend the cloud.  the only thing that does suck is you need to pay .  i was playing around with it a year ago and accidentally got a bill for 50bucks.  i called and explained and they refunded me but thats a one time thing.  i would build your REST server and file host server locally for testing and maybe even into your first few weeks.  it all matters how much traffic and storage you need and when.  the cloud auto expands.

Comment: know of any good tutorials on how to build a REST server and file host server for testing. Never actually done anything with servers before so anything would be appreciated. And thanks again.

Comment: there are alot of REST tutorials out there.  this one looks good and uses jax-ws (http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/) here is another that uses cxf (u should also know or understand maven for this one) (http://www.insaneprogramming.be/?p=140).   another really cool one is amazon has an eclipse plugin for webservices/REST.  but from what i had seen they didnt have any tutorials (at least for REST services).  REST is a really great technology and knowing it is good for your resume too)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all your help. It was very helpful.